# Error class in Java

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to understand the `Error` class in Java.

I have a good understanding of the `Exception` class, but can't find examples of code for the `Error` class. I've tried searching the web and also the java.sun website, but I'm not finding anything useful to help me understand this better.

How do I use the `Error` class in programs and where do we have to use that?

Comment: what is your exact requirement.can you detail it more.

Comment: i want to know the use of Error class and where we have to use that

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You don't use `Error` in your code.

An `Error` is a specific kind of `Throwable`, just as `Exception` is.

- [`Throwable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) is the base class that defines everything that can be thrown.
- [`Exception`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) is the common case. It is about problems that occur during the execution of your program.

  - [`RuntimeException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) is a special case: it's unchecked (i.e. it need not be declared by a method and the compiler doesn't force you to catch it).
- [`Error`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) is the "rare" case: it signifies problems that are outside the control of the usual application: JVM errors, out of memory, problems verifying bytecode: these are things that you *should not handle* because if they occur things are already so bad that your code is unlikely to be able to handle it sanely.

You should not attempt to correct the situation that resulted in an `Error`. You might want to catch it in order to log it and then rethrow it (see the JavaDoc of [`ThreadDeath`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadDeath.html) for an example on why you need to rethrow it (thanks to @krock for the heads-up)).

There is no other reason to throw any `Error` (i.e. don't create an `Error` on your own and throw it, if you think you want to do that, use an `Exception` or a `RuntimeException` instead).

Comment: *...you could catch an Error...* if you catch an Error you should generally rethrow it (see javadoc for [ThreadDeath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadDeath.html) for one reason why)

Comment: btw I wasn't the downvoter, just adding my thoughts, +1 for a good summary of the exception hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks, krok, I rephrased the final bit to clarify the need to re-throw when an `Error` is caught.

Comment: Then what is the need of a class Error when it is not used and it throws abnormal exceptions ? And what is the need to throw that Error object ...any how if there is abnormal error the application going to be stopped

Comment: @satheesh: while *application code* should not throw an `Error`, the JVM can (and will). Look at [`OutOfMemoryError`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html). There's usually not much the application can do, if that happens. At best it can try to safe the ongoing work, but even that might fail (the JVM is out of memory after all!).

Comment: For those that use Eclipse, have you ever had it run out of memory? It essentially catches this, gives you the option of continuing or restarting. In the case of OutOfMemory your app might be able to free up enough to save critical work as a last ditch effort.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the Javadoc [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) there is a good explanation:

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such errors are abnormal conditions.

Concerning the usage you also have this:

> A method is not required to declare in its throws clause any subclasses of Error that might be thrown during the execution of the method but not caught, since these errors are abnormal conditions that should never occur.

Answer (score 0):

> **Error**
>
> Error a subclass of "Throwable" class is thrown by java runtime system and indicate some unrecoverable conditions during the execution of the programs
>     Once thrown difficult to recover from it and the application get to halt.
>    Eg..,java.lang.StackOverflowError and java.lang.OutofMemoryError

// **An example code which throws StackOverflowError**

```
public class ErrorDemo
   {
          public void method1()
            {
                   this.method2();
            }

          public void method2()
           {
                    this.method1();
           }

 public static void main(String sri[])
           {
                ErrorDemo k= new ErrorDemo();
                     k.method1();
            }
 }
```

In this code from main method we are calling method1 and from method1 a call was  made   to method2 and again from method2 we are calling method1 means we created a continous loop which doesn't goes to end and finally **a critical error StackOverflowError** is being thrown.